# JQuery - Remove checkbox from a selected in dropdown

Tags: jquery, checkbox, drop-down-menu, hide

i know the title is a bit wired.

what i want is that i have a dropdown, theres some options in there, two of those options are "special". When you choose one of those two, 3 checkboxes should be gryed out/removed/ect..

heres some code:

HTML:

```
//THE DROPDOWN
<select id="pow-abo" style="float:left;">
<option id="data6" value="149">XXXX</option>
<option id="data11" value="199">XXXX</option>
</select>

//THE CHECKBOXES
<div id="pakkerPow">
<input id="surfstart" type="checkbox" value="29" />XXXX<br/>
<input id="surfmini" type="checkbox" value="49" />XXXX<br/>
<input id="surfmaxi" type="checkbox" value="99" />XXXX<br/>
</div>
```

Jquery:

```
// THE JQUERY DROPDOWN
$('#pow-abo').change(function (){
    powAbo = parseFloat($('#pow-abo').val());
    if($('#pow-abo').id() == 'data6' || $('#pow-abo').id() == 'data11')
    {
        $('#surfstart').hide();
        $('#surfmini').hide();
        $('#surfmaxi').hide();
    }
    visResultat2();
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of problems with your code. They centre around your `if` statement. Look at the following snippet:

```
$('#pow-abo').id()
```

The first problem is that `id` is not a method of a jQuery object. The second problem is that `#pow-abo` is the `select` element, not the selected option. It looks like you are trying to get the `id` of the selected option.

To get the selected option, as a DOM element (not a jQuery object) you could do something like this:

```
var selected = $(this).find(":selected")[0];
```

You would then be able to use `selected.id` to get the `id` of the selected option:

```
$('#pow-abo').change(function () {
    var selected = $(this).find(":selected")[0],
        powAbo = parseFloat($('#pow-abo').val());
    if(selected.id == 'data6' || selected.id == 'data11') {
        $('#surfstart').hide();
        $('#surfmini').hide();
        $('#surfmaxi').hide();
    }
});
```

Note that you could also shorten the `hide` calls into one:

```
$("#surfstart, #surfmini, #surfmaxi").hide();
```

Or, to hide all the checkboxes inside `#pakkerPow`:

```
$("#pakkerPow :checkbox").hide();
```

Comment: Thanks, this did the job.. How do it remove the text also, that comes with the Checkbox ?

Comment: If you want to hide everything inside `#pakkerPow` why not just hide that: `$("#pakkerPow").hide();`?

Comment: Dont want to hide every option, just the those 3 options, and the text that comes with it.. <input id="surfstart" type="checkbox" value="29" />TEXT HERE<br/>

Comment: The easiest way would be to wrap each of the things you want to hide in an element (`span` for example) and give those elements the same class. Then you could just do `$(".classToHide").hide();` *Edit:* Or wrap them with something like a `div`, as you've discovered :)

Comment: No problem, glad I could help :)

Answer (score 1):

I would do it this way: http://jsfiddle.net/pZcAF/6/

In short:

- you have a couple of errors in your jQuery
- you `hide()` the checkboxes instead of disabling them
- you never re-enable (or `show()`) them back

Additional feature in the example (as a bonus, in case you find it useful):

- checks for a given class on the "special" options (allows you to have a dynamically created list of special options)

Comment: This is a much better and _not sloppy_ solution.

Answer (score 0):

In order to 'grey out' or disable a form element, you have to add the disabled attribute to the element.

**Instead of**

```
$('#surfstart').hide();
```

**Do this**

```
$('#surfstart').attr('disabled','disabled');
```

**To enable a disabled element**

`$('#surfstart').removeAttr('disabled')`;

Answer (score 0):

if you really want to use show and hide take a look at this demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/xAcz7/

Instead of looking at the id im looking at the values, which is hide for options 1 and 2 and show for option 3.
And instead of hiding the 3 checkboxes im just hiding the div that contains the checkboxes. saves you lines of code ;)
Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Your test should be on the select value, not on ids:

```
 // THE JQUERY DROPDOWN
$('#pow-abo').change(function (){
  powAbo = parseFloat($(this).val());
  if(powAbo == '199' || powAbo == '149')
  {
    $("#pakkerPow input").attr("disabled", "disabled");
  }
  visResultat2();
});
```